# Marginal Distribution involving Bernoulli Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

For a random sample from $f(x|\theta) = \theta^x(1-\theta)^{1-x} \ \text{for}\ \ 0<\theta<1, \ \ x=0,1 $

$$ \pi(\theta) \propto \theta^{a-1}(1-\theta)^{b-1}\ \text{for} \ \ a>0, b>0.$$

Derive the marginal of X and find $E(X)$ using iterated expectation.

I do not understand this question, neither am I familiar with how to obtain marginal  for discrete distributions. Since it is asking to derive a marginal distribution, can I assume the distribution is a product of each distribution and thus, we have a joint distribution?

Comment: To find marginals, use the fact that $$\mathbb{P}(X=0)=\int_0^1f(0|\theta)\pi(\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta$$ $$\mathbb{P}(X=1)=1-\mathbb{P}(X=0)$$

Comment: Thank you @MatthewH. Does that mean we would have 2 marginals?